# Using google shared contacts api locally and on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, contacts, google-api

I noticed something strange when creating shared contact using google contacts api.
This is code i am using to create contact:

```
def AddEmail(name ,email):
   new_contact = gdata.contacts.ContactEntry(title=atom.Title(text=name))
   new_contact.email.append(gdata.contacts.Email(address=email,
                                           primary='true',
                                           rel=gdata.contacts.REL_WORK))
   create_contact = gd_client.CreateContact(new_contact)
   print create_contact.link[2].href
```

Of course there are keys, accounts and stuff so it works. Strange
thing happens when i run it locally, saved as some *.py file, 
`print create_contact.link[2].href` actually prints out edit link for contact. When i deploy it on GAE
result is link to contact but not edit link, like i would use `print create_contact.link`. Code stays same, i use self.response.out.write though on GAE for testing purposes only finally it should go to datastore.
I do not see difference, what am i missing? what i do not know about
GAE?